# T-SQL and Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am having difficulty trying to find out why my t-sql string is coming up with an error message as you can see I have created this sql to pull information from other tables to create a capacity table, however something is not right and I cant figure out what it is. Can you help. Thanks in advance.

Error message:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 32
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

SQL script:

```
DECLARE @PitchType_Skey INT
DECLARE @Site_Skey INT
DECLARE @Capacity INT
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

SET @PitchType_Skey = 1
SET @Site_Skey = 1
SET @Capacity = 0


WHILE (@Site_Skey < 127)

BEGIN
  IF @PitchType_Skey = 8

  BEGIN

    SET @PitchType_Skey = 1
    SET @Site_Skey = @Site_Skey + 1

  END

  IF (@Site_Skey < 127)

  BEGIN

    Set @Capacity = (SELECT SiteWeighting From Site Where Site_Skey = @Site_Skey)
    Set @Capacity = @Capacity * (SELECT PitchTypeWeighting From PitchType  Where PitchType_Skey = @PitchType_Skey)
    Set @Capacity = @Capacity * ((10*(100+((RAND()*40)-20)))*0.01)

    INSERT INTO Capacity2
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '01 May 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '01 May 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '01 May 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '01 May 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '01 May 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '01 May 2015'

        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '1 Apr 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '25 Mar 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '10 Mar 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '01 Apr 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '01 Mar 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '15 Mar 2015'

        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '1 Apr 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '25 Mar 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '10 Mar 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '01 Apr 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '01 Mar 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '15 Mar 2015'

        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '01 Jan 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '01 Jan 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '01 Jan 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '01 Jan 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '01 Jan 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '01 Jan 2015'

        ELSE NULL
      END as StartDate,

      CASE
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '30 Sep 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '30 Sep 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '30 Sep 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '30 Sep 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '30 Sep 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 1 THEN '30 Sep 2015'

        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '01 Nov 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '05 Nov 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '02 Nov 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '08 Nov 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '01 Nov 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 2 THEN '03 Nov 2015'

        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '01 Nov 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '05 Nov 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '02 Nov 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '08 Nov 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '01 Nov 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 3 THEN '03 Nov 2015'

        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2010 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '31 Dec 2010'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2011 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '31 Dec 2011'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2012 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '31 Dec 2012'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2013 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '31 Dec 2013'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2014 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '31 Dec 2014'
        WHEN YEAR(@EndDate) = 2015 AND (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey) = 4 THEN '31 Dec 2015'

        ELSE NULL
      END,

      ROUND(@Capacity,0) as Capacity,
      @PitchType_Skey, @Site_Skey

  END
  SET @PitchType_Skey = @PitchType_Skey + 1

END
```

Comment: What's the table definition for `Capacity2`? Where do `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` get their values? What is the type of `PitchTypeWeighting`? What is the type of `SiteWeighting`?

Comment: Hi Lieven

The '@StartDate' and '@EndDate' get their values from the When Statement, the When Statement pulls a number between 1 and 4 from the Site Table to determine the date. Both the 'Weightings' are Int.

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting into the `Capacity2` table without specifying which values go into which columns to put each value into. I'm guessing that this is the cause of the problem, and it's trying to put your one of your other integer values into your start date column.

You haven't posted your schema so I can only guess your column names, but I suggest you change the insert part of your script to be like:

```
INSERT INTO Capacity2 (StartDate, EndDate, Capacity, PitchTypeKey, Site_SKey)
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN ...
```

That way there is no ambiguity as to which value you want inserted into which column.

Comment: Hi Bridge,

This didn't work, my '@StartDate' and '@EndDate' came back with Null values.

Thanks

Comment: @wafw1971 What does having null values have to do with specifying the names of the columns to insert into?

Comment: Once I followed your advice, my table populated but the'@StartDate' and '@EndDate' columns had not dates in only the word Null. My column names worked fine as per the script above it just wouldn't populate.

Comment: @wafw1971 So the error message is gone and it ran successfully? This question is answered then - if you have a second thing to ask, I'd suggest you post a new question. That aside, I'm assuming you have values which don't match any criteria in your case statement then, check the values where you get null in the final result to see why. One more thing - you don't need to put `ELSE NULL` on the end of a `case` statement; SQL Server will return NULL for any value that doesn't match any of your predicates anyway.

Comment: Hi Bridge, the original question still stands what you asked me to do didn't work. I may not have asked in the right because I am new to SQL but when I only had one year it work fine as is, it doesn't work when I add all the other years into the equation.

Comment: @wafw1971 I read the original question as "help me fix this error message", which I have. As to the logic of what you're trying to do, that _is_ a different question if you ask me. Good luck!

Comment: @wafw1971: It's all right, you asked the correct question. You were facing an issue and asked just about that. And this answer resolves that problem. Your new question is entirely different, even though it relates to the same tables, same data etc. Please ask it in a new post. This is really how things work best on this site: one problem – one question. We want to help *you* and we *also* want existing questions to be helpful to others. That's why we don't like to make them messy.